# ArcGIS Modelbuilder: Merge features from same layer into one feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, editing, merge

How can I merge two features from the same layer into one feature when using the Model Builder?

Outside of the model builder, this can easily be done with the Edit Tool. How can I make the same process work in Modelbuilder?

Also, is there a way to automatically tell Modelbuilder to chose the Feature with the lower Value of Field-X to be the "Parent-feature"?

I work with ArcGIS 10.1
I also asked the question on Geonet: https://geonet.esri.com/message/608891

Comment: How you are going to decide what are the two features that are to be merged? When you do it with the Edit-Tool you do it manually by your interpretation or do they have a common value or special position? The task is possible in the Modelbuilder, but only when the features to be merged can be selected automaticly via a certain value or spatial rule.

Comment: Make a tool that takes an input layer and does merging etc.stuffs and returns intended feature- after all include this tool in the model builder..

Comment: @Matte I made the automatic selection already in the Modelbuilder
SLslam: can you explain it a bit more?